# how to have custom URL in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I want to have a custom URL like domainname/#/topic
where topic is any string.

Currently I have domainname/topic , I have done this via routes.php

```
$route['(.*)'] = 'topic/view/$1';
```

so here view method of topic controller is called.

I want to have same thing but with # in the URL.

How can I achieve this??

Thanks,
Aniket

Answer (score 0):

Use $route['(:any)'] to allow for anything.

Please note that CodeIgniter does have some built in "allowed characters", so you may need to modify that.

To change the allowed characters, I recommend seeing the solution in this post:

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/133858/

Comment: i am having domain/username currently and i want to have domain/#/topic so there are both things which I want, i already have done domain/username

Comment: You'll need to allow the # character I believe, but browsers interpret the # character as an identifier locator/anchor, so it won't reload a page if it has a hash put on the end.

Comment: i did $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-#'; but its not working

Comment: just added #  at the end to what was there

Comment: The "permitted_uri_chars" is in regular expression format, so the # symbol has special meaning. add a backslash \ in front of the #. Does that work? Ah you already have...

Comment: I'm not sure I why you want to do this to be honest. have you tried doing something like $route['#/(:any)'] = 'topic/view/$1'; ?

Comment: $route['#/(:any)'] = 'topic/view/$1'; doesn't work and having # in the url is just the requirement

Comment: I don't think this is possible then due to the behaviour of the # symbol. You would need to use AJAX to get the content, as CodeIgniter sees anything beginning with a # as the index page (Just tested it with a variety of ways).

Comment: will i be able to get that there is a # in the url and then make ajax request. isn't there a way where in controller i can get the # from the url??

Comment: Just found this: Note that anything that comes after the # will not be passed to the server through GET parameters.

Comment: ohh then i guess there is no way to achieve this

Comment: any idea how http://www.so.cl/#/explore is happening?? so.cl has # at many places how do those people do this??

Comment: That link just takes me to the home page, the exact same location as so.cl ... so I can't say how they do it. Twitter etc use AJAX to do it however.

Comment: by ajax can i get whatever string is there after # example if url is /#/apple then i need to fetch this apple then do back-end stuff based on it

Comment: I know that. But it takes me to the same page as just /, so I can't say how they specifically do it without signing up. I think this discussion should be over now, and  you need to look into using AJAX to pull in information if you need to really have the # in the URL.

Comment: Yes you can use AJAX to do that.